# Spatie Query Builder filter nested relations

Tags: laravel, query-builder, laravel-query-builder

Using Spatie Query Builder I would like to extend the filters on nested relationships

The following code fetches locations with the relation jobs counts which works fine. I would like to extend the filter on job relation to can query relation job.level which is a many to many. How would I go for?

the filter would look like `/options/?filter[job.level]=2`

**Germany - 12,
Italy - 34**

```
  $locations = QueryBuilder::for(JobLocation::class)
            ->select('id as value', 'title', 'country_id')
            ->orderBy('title')
            ->withCount(['job as counts' => function ($q) {
                $q->whereNull('deleted_at');
            }])
            ->whereHas('country', function ($q) {
                $q->where('id', '=', 80);
            })
            ->allowedAppends(
                'job',
            )
            ->allowedIncludes('job', 'job.level',)
            ->allowedFilters([
                AllowedFilter::exact('job.language_id'),
                AllowedFilter::exact('job.level', 'job.level.id')
            ])->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the whereHas function. See the docs for [querying relation existence here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence). But you are already doing this for the country relationship, this is not any different.

So I think yours would look something like:

```
  $locations = QueryBuilder::for(JobLocation::class)
        ->select('id as value', 'title', 'country_id')
        ->orderBy('title')
        ->withCount(['job as counts' => function ($q) {
            $q->whereNull('deleted_at');
        }])
        ->whereHas('country', function ($q) {
            $q->where('id', '=', 80);
        })
        //New query constraint here
        ->whereHas('job', function ($q) {
            $q->where('level', '=', 2);
        })
        ->allowedAppends(
            'job',
        )
        ->allowedIncludes('job', 'job.level',)
        ->allowedFilters([
            AllowedFilter::exact('job.language_id'),
            AllowedFilter::exact('job.level', 'job.level.id')
        ])->get();
```

Comment: thanks for Feedback! I thought that I can manage this with spatie query builder using the in-build filter method and don't need to extract the params from the requested url.

Comment: Note that whereHas is very expansive for the db, I highly recommend using join instead. https://youtu.be/JOnXX-N96NE?t=184